# Keep hourly backups for two weeks instead of one with Time Machine

Tags: backup, time-machine

How can I tweak Time Machine to keep the hourly backups for two weeks instead of just one?

Comment: Resume, my question is, I want to have a backup of every hour not for a week (standard configuration of time machine), but for two weeks. How can do it?